# Build and interact with contract

Tags: tokens, transfer, smart-contract-wallets

I'm developing a new token and I'm curious how I can interact with the token after is build and deployed. For example:

Token1 has 10M tokens of total supply, I want people to can get those tokens, how I can do that? Also, I want transfers between people, which holds my token, and connecting my contract to a wallet.

Is even that possible with smart contracts?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Investigate about ERC20 tokens. They should provide all the features you are looking for..

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to build it on ERC20.